# Py2exe Including a DLL in Library.zip

Tags: python, ctypes, py2exe

I use ctypes on Windows to access a DLL. Generally, I wrap the DLL with a .py of the same name and add additional support for the DLL such as ctypes structs that are used with some of the functions. I load the DLL use the following technique.

```
# Determine the absolute path to the DLL that resides in the same directory as this module.
absolute_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'monty.dll')

interface = ctypes.CDLL(absolute_path)
```

The module is part of a package that I maintain and I'd like to use Py2exe with bundle_files set to 1 to create fewer files. I am happy to have library.zip sitting alongside my .exe.

So the obvious problem is that monty.py will be trying to access monty.dll and it will expect that path to be .../library.zip/root/dll/monty.dll.

I found a way to package the DLL in library.zip but I suspect ctypes is rejecting the path within the .zip file. Windows complains that it cannot load the module.

Getting the above to work would be my first choice but a fallback might be to have everything in library.zip except my package. Any ideas as to how this can be accomplished?

Comment: The `data_files` option lets you put the DLL alongside the exe, right? Then you can use `CDLL('monty.dll')`.